# MongoDb journal in write concern

Tags: mongodb, journal

I wrote a test program to check mongodb write performance with or without journaling:
Items to be inserted: 10000

**case1:** 
insert with `(w = 1, j = 1)` result: 10000 documents inserted in **340,620 ms** (about **29** documents per second)

**case2:** 
insert with `(w = 0, j = 1)` result: 10000 documents inserted in **360ms** (about **27700** documents per second)

What does `(w = 0, j = 1)` mean?

do we have durability in case2?

Comment: If the code has not changed it means nothing much really, except that it will make jornal commits a third of their natural time. Without the write concern it will not wait

Comment: Is it durable for sure? journal will commit? Then what is so difference in performance (about 1000 times slower than w = 1)

Comment: The wite is as durable as if you had w=1, the reason for the speed is because you are using w=0, this overwrites the j=1 wait time and makes only the effect of journal being commit in shorter intervals (which is what happens normally)

Comment: It should be noted that this does mean you have no notification of the writes durability but it should be immune to network errors between your app and the mongod instance you wish to talk to as described in the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#unacknowledged so it isn't as bad as fire and forget but it will not wait for MongoDB to acknowledge or process the operation

Comment: I think I got my answer, write your comments as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing that the working of journaled has not changed in the last version I believe what you are seeing is the speed of `w=0`. Since you have `w=0` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#unacknowledged ) you are only acknowledging that the command was sent to the MongoDB instance(s).

The behaviour of `w=0` was changed from socket acknowledged in earlier versions of MongoDB which could not mitigate network errors because of that.

So the value of `w=0` is overriding the value of `j=1` and causing unacknowledged writes, however, the durability should theorticially be the same since `j=1` still causes:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#journaled

> MongoDB also increases the frequency that it commits operations to the journal.

But:

> Unacknowledged is similar to errors ignored; however, drivers will attempt to receive and handle network errors when possible.

Good to note that "errors ignored". If you get an error while updating/inserting them you would not be told about it, but ignoring documents with errors, your durability should be relatively the same.

Of course, it is not as good as actually doing a `w=1` but it is not as bad as socket acknowledged (old `w=0`) which could lose massive amounts of writes.

So you are getting the speed of `w=0` with short intervals to journal as if they are all journal acknowledged.

Comment: "however, the durability should theorticially be the same" It is not. where w:1 guarantees that the data is written to at least one node's data file, j:1 only reduced the period between journal writes. Case 1: A w:1,j:1 returns. The data has already be written to a data file. Case 2: a w:0,j:1 returns: The data has not necessarily be written to a journal, and an outage of the respective server may still lead to the data being lost.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg theoritically provided there is not errorm within MongoDB itself w=0 should not lose data over the network if it can handle network errors, that is the condition of my statement

Comment: Oh I was wrong, too. Too early here. Actually j:1 forces the data being committed to the journal, reducing the commit interval the same time. While there still may be situations where those changes do not make it to the data file (really "well" timed outages or network partitions in a replica set), for the majority of cases when looking at a single node j:1 is equal to w:1 for all practical purposes.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg they have since removed the documentation on the effects of `j:1` on the journal interval but if I remember right it brings it down to 1/3rd of its normal time which is like 23ms, so there is a window of 23ms if an error were to occur and failover proceeded

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg sorry 10ms since the default has been changed to 30ms now

Comment: Iirc it is dynamically calculated as 1/3 of `journalCommitInterval`, so it would be either 33 ms if the datafile and the journal live on the same block device or 10 ms if the data files and the journal live on different block devices.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg ah yeah read the wrong sentence on the page (or rather only that bit and not the bit above), it related to separate block device. It should be confirmed that, from 10gen themselves, I have been told that even though interval is set at 100ms, it can be closer to 60ms normally